In Android, deeplink from Chrome browser to Amazon app. Intent, package, scheme?
I have a website and am adding Amazon affiliate linking. Currently, my affiliate links open in the Amazon website, but I want them to open in the Amazon app.
I'm wondering if Amazon has an intent/scheme solution similar to how I am able to open my own (unrelated) app from a browser using the below format:
<a href="intent://MYAPP_URLPATH/#Intent;scheme=MYAPP_SCHEME;package=MYAPP_PACKAGE;end">open page in app</a>

Or maybe another way? Some people use a service like joturl or URLgenius, which creates the deeplinks, but it seems that if they can do it, then so can I? Or do these services have some kind of deal with Amazon?
Note, I'm not trying to open Amazon from an app, but from a browser, such as Chrome. This is in Android.

Got it. Works in iOS and Android.
Note that this doesn't redirect if the user doesn't have the app installed. Then it fails silently.
I tested it and it does seem that the affiliate tag gets passed correctly and register as a link.
Grab the product page's full affiliate link. Then replace
https://www.amazon.com/

with
com.amazon.mobile.shopping.web://amazon.com/

So you get an URL like this, of course with your tag and the correct linkId:
com.amazon.mobile.shopping.web://amazon.com/LEGO-Valentines-Flower/dp/B0CDCL6Y5T?th=1&linkCode=ll1&tag=YOUR_TAG&linkId=THE_LINK_ID&language=en_US&ref_=as_li_ss_tl

You can use that in html:
<a href = "the_url">buy</a>

or javascript:
location.href = the_url

